# Type? of text blocks regEx function

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have recently started to use `regEx` for work and have now found a rather peculiar problem which I apparently can't solve myself...

Problem: I receive data from customers (from all over the world) and have to analyze it. The data this time has some specialties.

e.g. for raw data:

`Screw М4х20 , DIN7985`           - This is the original text **with** the problem

`Screw M4x20 , DIN7985`           - This is manual written text, which gives me 
                                perfect results

If I now try to pick out the dimension "M4x20" with following `regEx`:

```
(\b[M]?\d+x\d+\b)
```

it yields me no results... neither in Excel, nor in websites like `regExr`:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ka9jHv/1/)

If I delete the `M4x20` and write it a new, I do get [**results**](https://regex101.com/r/ka9jHv/2).

I have absolutely no idea where the problem lies, except that **it is caused by the M char and the x char** - for reference: the rest of the text/letters (a-z) also doesn't work. The numbers are working ok.

Is there some way to analyze it?

**Edit:**

There is and I just found out: The letters are [Cyrillic letters](https://unicode-table.com/de/041C/) which are not being recognized.
Though they can apparently be changed to latin letters quite easily.

Comment: Maybe try using a site like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) where you or others can play with the regex pattern.

Comment: as I said, the regexpattern is not a problem, the problem is the datatype.

Comment: Posting images of your pattern is not helpful to others — that is what I am explaining.

Comment: Yes. Actually, the M char and the x char are not being recognized. I just don't know, how to analyze them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two chars [`M`](https://unicode-table.com/de/041C/) and [`x`](https://unicode-table.com/de/0445/) are part of Cyrillic letters and they are represented in regex as `\u041C` (`M`) and `\u0445` (`x`).

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEfj1P/1)

**VBA code**:

```
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Global = True

re.Pattern = "\u041C?\d+\u0445\d+"
For Each Match In re.Execute("Screw М4х20 , DIN7985")
    Debug.Print (Match)
Next
```

Output:

```
М4х20
```

Comment: awesome , my solution to it wasn't quite as neat, as this one. Didn't even know that you could access Unicode in regex like that! Thanks so much!